# How can I automatically chmod a file created by a systemd service?

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service that starts go-ethereum (geth), which then creates an Unix socket that is used to provide a control console. My problem is that my user can't connect to the Unix socket because, although my user and the service's user are both in the same group and the file created is automatically owned by both the service user and the group, the geth process doesn't automatically give rw permission to the group. I can fix this myself by running `sudo chmod 660 /path/to/socket` from a terminal before using it's console, but I would like to do this automatically if possible.

What I've tried is adding a rule like this to the `[Service]` section of the service file: `ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod 660 /path/to/socket`. This doesn't work though, I believe because there is a delay between the service process starting and it creating the socket. The `ExecStartPost` command then fails, which in turn appears to cause the service to shut down.

One option I can see for fixing this is to write a script that checks for the existence of the file repeatedly, and then modifies the file's permissions once the file is detected. Then I could change the rule to `ExecStartPost=/path/to/script`. A simpler and possibly less robust solution in the same vein might be make the rule `ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c "sleep 5 && /bin/chmod 660 /path/to/socket"`.

Is this kind of solution the best option or does systemd provide some other/simpler mechanism that could be used for my purpose?

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership of the directory that contains the socket?

Comment: I would stick to systemd, but cant help with that. If everything fails use `inotify`.

Comment: @NasirRiley the directory is owned by both the service user and the group, and the permissions for the directory are 775.

Comment: Have you tried changing the directory permissions to `02775`?

Comment: Is changing the service an option? What service is it? If it is not well-known, can you tell details about it? Please add all clarification or requested information to the question instead of answering in comments. You can [edit] your question to do this.

Comment: Try changing the `UMask` of the service (0002 rather than the default 0022), it’s possible that the executable just uses the default permissions. I’ve successfully used this technique with OpenDKIM/OpenDMARC, SpamAssassin, and gitweb, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic guiding principle here is that *whatever binds the `AF_LOCAL` socket should be setting its permissions*.  Doing otherwise is a rickety Heath Robinson contraption.

If the dæmon service program creates and binds the socket, then look for configuration options that allow you to specify the socket's permissions.  Unfortunately, you may find that the program's authors might not have thought that people needed to do this.

If the dæmon service program does not have such a configuration mechanism, then look to making the dæmon service program *receive* its control socket at startup as an already open file descriptor, passed information about this file descriptor via the `LISTEN_FDS` mechanism (as presumably it is a listening socket that accepts connection requests).  Then it is service management that is responsible for creating and binding the socket and setting its permissions, which systemd *does* have knobs for.

Then set up an `Accept=No` systemd socket unit describing that socket, including the appropriate `ListenStream` setting (as presumably the control interface is a stream socket one) and a `SocketMode=0660` setting.

Comment: I think I've found another solution. If I change the ownership of the service executable, which is the same executable used to connect to the console, and I add the setuid bit to it, then I think I will be able to access the console without changing the socket's permissions. Is this also considered hackish?

Comment: @Broseph Setting setuid bit to executable is very dangerous - if the executable is not very precisely designed for such purpose (like passwd or sudo), it can allow run any other unintended command as the executable owner.